# SUM SQL запрос, как правильно?

Tags: sql

Помогите пожалуйста правильно составить SQL запрос.
Есть таблица TABLE и поля user, balance, и referal. В поле referal записан логин партнера.

Задача: нужно посчитать общее количество средств SUM(balance) для каждого партнера (referal) и вывести их отсортировав от большего к меньшему, должна получится табличка общей привлеченной суммы (balance) каждого партнера(referal).

Comment: Можете предоставить схему таблиц или хотя бы поля, а то не понятно как они связанны друг с другом, за исключением таблицы referal

Comment: прошу прощение, есть таблица TABLE, а поля user, balance, и referal. Немного затупил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT referal, SUM(balance) AS sum_balance FROM `table` GROUP BY referal
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я все правильно понял

```
SELECT *, SUM(balance)
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY referal
ORDER BY SUM(balance) DESC
```

Comment: А если вы не правильно поняли?

Comment: Евгений, спасибо, но к сожалению, вы немного неправильно поняли, вы вывели все записи, а необходимо посчитать во всех записях ОБЩУЮ сумму поля balance для каждого партнера (таблица: referal) и вывести подобный результат: referal и общую сумму поля balance.

Comment: Сможет кто-то помочь?

Comment: Что бы все прояснилось, можете предоставить схему БД необходимых таблиц.

Answer (score 0):

Так будет правильней

```
SELECT referal, SUM(balance) AS total 
FROM table 
GROUP BY referal
ORDER BY total DESC
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]