# Вывести только уникальные значения

Tags: mysqli

У меня есть база данных. В ней содержится:

```
ID | TAG
1  | Valera
2  | Andrey 
3  | Anna
4  | Valera
5  | Anna
```

Мне нужно получать только 1 значение TAG не взирая на дубликаты:

```
1 | Valera
2 | Andrey
3 | Anna
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [SUM SQL запрос, как правильно?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/779549/sum-sql-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be)

Comment: Так ^^^ только вместо sum использовать min, что бы получить минимальный id для заданного tag

Answer (score 2):

Существует оператор distinct для получения уникальных значений:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `TAG` FROM `table`
```