# Как сделать выборку из БД с суммированием данных?

Tags: mysql

есть таблица с табелем работы (учетом рабочего времени), важные поля в ней

```
date(XXXX-XX-XX) | id работника | часы отработанного времени
```

есть такие строки в которых в одной дате один и тот же пользователь указан несколько раз
надо как то отловить этот момент и приплюсовать его часы , что бы результат был 1 пользователь за 1 дату и с суммой часов в одну строчку. Может быть 1,2,3+ записи у одного пользователя за 1 день , а может быть только 1
как правильно написать запрос такой?

Comment: GROUP BY + SUM()

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [SUM SQL запрос, как правильно?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/779549/sum-sql-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Группировка по date, id и SUM(часы).

```
SELECT date, user_id, SUM(hours) FROM user_dolg GROUP BY date, user_id
```